# Is there an easy to get random number from the range in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have checked [THIS](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/android+studio+random+number+generator+kotlin) example but my studio do not see this function and not import is. Is there a similar way ?

This one not import `val randomNumber = (100..200).random()`

Answer (score 1):

```
@SinceKotlin("1.3")
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun IntRange.random(): Int {
return random(Random)
}
```

`random()` is extension function on `IntRange` in the `ktx` library  introduced in `kotlin 1.3` make sure you're using kotlin 1.3 or above and using `core ktx`
`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'`
not `implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'`

you can also achieve same thing using `Random.nextInt(100,200)`

Comment: It has nothing to do with AndroidX libraries. It’s in the Kotlin standard library.

Comment: @Tenfour04 if you don't core-ktx that function is not available I tried myself then answered

Comment: Probably a project setup issue. With older versions of the Kotlin gradle plugin, you have to manually include the standard library dependency. If you failed to do this, using `core-ktx` would have loaded the Kotlin standard library as a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to avoid that library here is a roundabout way of doing it:

```
val random = Random
val myInt = 100 + random.nextInt(100)
println(myInt)
```

Note that myInt will be between 100 and 200.